# How to handle empty values produced by NLog's all-event-properties layout renderer?

Tags: c#, postgresql, nlog, npgsql, hstore

I'm configuring NLog's database target for PostgreSQL and I want to use [`hstore` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/hstore.html) to store all event properties. I'm using [`all-event-properties` layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/All-Event-Properties-Layout-Renderer) for that.

Here's my current target configuration:

```
<target name="database"
        xsi:type="Database"
        dbProvider="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql"
        connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=db;User Id=postgres">
  <install-command>
    <text>
      CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore WITH SCHEMA public;
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs (
      id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
      moment timestamp NOT NULL,
      level text NOT NULL,
      message text NOT NULL,
      args hstore NOT NULL
      );
    </text>
  </install-command>
  <commandText>
    INSERT INTO logs (moment, level, message, args)
    VALUES (@moment::timestamp, @level, @message, @args::hstore);
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@moment" layout="${longdate:universalTime=true}" />
  <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />

  <!-- (!) Here's where the format of event properties adopted for hstore syntax (!)-->
  <parameter name="@args" layout="${all-event-properties:format=[key]=>[value]" />

</target>
```

It works for logs without parameters, but with parameters the following SQL is generated:

```
INSERT INTO logs (moment, level, message, args) VALUES (
'2019-05-24 18:44:49.7494'::timestamp,
'Info',
'Message text here',
'a=>1, b=>2, c=>3, EventId_Id=>555, EventId_Name=>, EventId=>555'::hstore);
--                           no value here--------^
```

Which is invalid syntax, because PostgreSQL syntax needs either `NULL` keyword for value or not to include the key at all:

Here's the error:

```
ERROR:  Syntax error near 'E' at position 51
```

Which exactly reproduces when I'm executing this by hand and goes away when I remove `EventId_Name=>,` key. So, I'm pretty sure I need somehow to skip/handle those empty key to be happy.

I'm also OK with any solution in SQL, but can't find a simple and robust approach to handle those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what the syntax should be in this case, but you can fix this anyway with a custom layout renderer

create:

```
// register ${all-properties-postgresql}
LayoutRenderer.Register("all-properties-postgresql", 
                       (logEvent) => SerializeProps(logEvent.Properties));
```

You need to write `SerializeProps` to serialize the `LogEventInfo.Properties` - see [API docs](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.6.0/html/P_NLog_LogEventInfo_Properties.htm)

Comment: Thinks he wants an `IncludeEmptyValue` property for `$[all-event-properties}` (Default = true, but he wants to assign it false).

Comment: ah! But there isn't a IncludeEmptyValue option yet, isn't?

Comment: `IncludeEmptyValue` would be very helpful, but it doesn't exist yet: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/All-Event-Properties-Layout-Renderer 
Thanks, @Julian, that's really not that hard to implement own layout renderer in NLog

Comment: I've created a PR: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3423 and named it "IncludeEmptyValues"

Comment: Update, IncludeEmptyValues will be included in NLog 4.6.4

Comment: NLog 4.6.4 has been released: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.6.4

Answer (score 1):

To contribute to the answer, I've read the hstore [format documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/hstore.html):

> Double-quote keys and values that include whitespace, commas, =s or >s. To include a double quote or a backslash in a key or value, escape it with a backslash.

Not sure what is `=s` and `>s`, and I've decided to double-quote everything while escaping double quotes and backslashes. Here's my solution:

```
LayoutRenderer.Register("all-event-properties-hstore", e =>
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var first = true;
    var fp = e.FormatProvider ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    string GetString(object o) =>
        Convert.ToString(o, fp).Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
    foreach (var (key, value) in e.Properties)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append("\"");
        sb.Append(GetString(key));
        sb.Append("\"=>\"");
        sb.Append(GetString(value));
        sb.Append("\"");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
});
```

Comment: I think you could move `var fp...` outside the loop.